# Mailer default to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an Admin emailer:

```
class AdminMailer < ApplicationMailer
  ADMIN_EMAIL = 'admin@gmail.com'

  def send1
    mail(to: ADMIN_EMAIL, subject: 'You have a new registered user')
  end

end
```

Since it's an admin emailer, I wonder, is it possible to make mail send the emails to admin by default? Something like:

```
class AdminMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default to: 'admin@gmail.com'
```

I've never ever seen the option `to`, does it exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, default value can be set to `:to` parameter.

From the relevant part of the rails code base `# You can set default values for any of the above headers (except +:date+)`

See the code comments at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f6b21d48ef15d4f39a530653c2ce7d0cfb458b46/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L702-L729

```
# The main method that creates the message and renders the email templates. There are
# two ways to call this method, with a block, or without a block.
#
# It accepts a headers hash. This hash allows you to specify
# the most used headers in an email message, these are:
#
# * +:subject+ - The subject of the message, if this is omitted, Action Mailer will
#   ask the Rails I18n class for a translated +:subject+ in the scope of
#   <tt>[mailer_scope, action_name]</tt> or if this is missing, will translate the
#   humanized version of the +action_name+
# * +:to+ - Who the message is destined for, can be a string of addresses, or an array
#   of addresses.
# * +:from+ - Who the message is from
# * +:cc+ - Who you would like to Carbon-Copy on this email, can be a string of addresses,
#   or an array of addresses.
# * +:bcc+ - Who you would like to Blind-Carbon-Copy on this email, can be a string of
#   addresses, or an array of addresses.
# * +:reply_to+ - Who to set the Reply-To header of the email to.
# * +:date+ - The date to say the email was sent on.
#
# You can set default values for any of the above headers (except +:date+)
# by using the ::default class method:
#
#  class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
#    default from: 'no-reply@test.lindsaar.net',
#            bcc: 'email_logger@test.lindsaar.net',
#            reply_to: 'bounces@test.lindsaar.net'
#  end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Actually I wrapped `mail` into `mail_to_user` that sets default options because this method would send duplicate emails

You can do it in an after action:

```rb
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  after_action :set_default_to
  after_action :set_default_subject

  def set_default_to
    mail.to ||= user_email(current_user) if current_user
  end
  
  def set_default_subject
    mail.subject ||= I18n.t(subject_key)
  end
end
```